# Where is it appropriate to discuss typical "best [technology] for doing [x]"?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

Most questions of the type "Which framework should I use" are flame bait and extremely likely to attract very biased opinions. Yet people ask them (and get their questions closed), and at times one can get decent input on choosing a suitable tech.

Since StackOverflow is not a good fit, where does discussions like these go? Reddit?

Comment: A local user group?

Comment: I don't even know what that accounts to these days. With the internet replacing physical meeting points the concept of physical user groups seems to lose meaning. Especially when the topics are very specific and you live in a town that is not a metropolis, as the number of people knowing anything about a specific topic in such a vast technology jungle is very small.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is where such questions go on the SE network.

### However...

SR has very specific requirements for questions.  You should read the following articles and clearly understand and follow their requirements before posting a question there:

- [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)
- [How to ask and answer software recommendation questions - aka 'The Ground Rules'](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules)
- [You're doing it all wrong!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong)

In particular, SR has the same "no discussions" policy as every other Stack Exchange site.  If you're looking for a *discussion* and not answers, other Internet resources (or even an appropriate SE chat room) are probably a better fit.

Comment: To be fair, whilst you are 100% correct on the above link for Software Recommendations, it is not listed an off-topic alternative for the average viewer.  Whilst I appreciate we can't list every stack exchange site in that dialog - perhaps we can improve the closing/holding mechanic to an extent whereby experienced users can always pick the appropriate site?

Comment: @Moo-Juice the site hasn't even graduated, and the list of off-topic alternatives should be reserved for the *graduated* sites most likely to be more appropriate venues for *good* questions. I think if it were an option, again when it graduates, it would quickly become the porta-potty for all bad "what is the best ...?" shopping list-style questions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have to disagree here. If we don't promote the site, it might stay stuck in beta. If we on the other hand have an influx of questions there, we can better define the site and more effectively get it to graduation status. Concerning the porta-potty thing. usually it's enough to educate moderators (who have the migration power) to prevent most of that. remember: Don't migrate crap!

Comment: @Vogel612 When the heck did I say to not promote the site? I said to not include it in the default list of off-topic destinations, that's all. Because that WILL lead to a bunch of migrated crap.